# Ignite server node not able to reconnect

Tags: ignite

I have 2 server nodes working together in the same cluster as accepted
 Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=2, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=7.1GB]

If the connection (LAN)  lost and return after a while the nodes wouldn't reconnect
 Topology snapshot [ver=3, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=3.6GB]

How can server nodes reconnect after the connection lost?

setting reconnect count will work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was already answered here http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/How-can-server-nodes-reconnect-td3220.html

In case you will have two servers then there is no possibility to reconnect them. You should start new server node manually.

Client reconnection described here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/clients-vs-servers#section-client-reconnection

Comment: Thanks for quick response. then what is use of reconnection count  configuration ? and if i have 5 server nodes is it possible to implement reconnect ?

Comment: In case if server node lost connection to other nodes then it will wait for failure detection timeout. After that timeout, it can't join to the cluster as well. You can read about it here: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/IgniteConfiguration.html#getFailureDetectionTimeout--; Regarding to reconnection count configuration. I hope that you talk about this: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/TcpDiscoverySpi.html#setReconnectCount-int-. It works only for clients.